# The three houses going down on the right are marked as not valid, whats wrong with them?

Tags: terraria

I am having a problem with housing --- NPCs won't move into the houses on the right. I have already tried making them bigger, but it didn't help. What is wrong with these rooms?[image]

Comment: Try making them smaller (less wide in this case).   I would shave off 1 or 2 blocks on the right side.  There are [size limits](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/House#Size) to houses, and those might be too wide (or possibly too tall for the width in which case, lower the ceiling).

Comment: @TimmyJim those appear to be smaller than 20x20 (by a good deal) and 20x20 only has an area of 400 tiles. The maximum limit for a house area is 750 tiles. If it were a height issue, then the ones to the left would be affected as well. As for width, well, I've made houses way wider than those successfully. I'd suggest double checking that every single background tile is covered. Due to the way background tiles can overlap, sometimes an area can appear covered when it's not.

Answer (score 4):

The houses on the right are too close to the corruption. Try removing all corrupted stuff for some distance.

If you are in hardmode you can throw hallowed stuff around to turn it into hallow and fight the corruption that way, otherwise you'll have to use purifying powder (that you can buy from the dryad). Or bomb/mine it all away.

Make sure the corruption cannot creep back again after you've cleared it, or the houses will be invalidated again. (For example by digging a four wide tunnel around the part you want to defend, and line the walls of the tunnel with non-corruptible blocks. (for example all sorts of bricks work for this)